# jsfiddle example not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I'm trying to use jsfiddle to show the slick jquery based carousel. I haven't used jfiddle before, so I think I'm missing something. I'm trying to use it to collaborate with classmates on ideas for a project.

The issue is when I try to put the following in the html box, I get a bunch of errors .

```
No need for the HTML tag, it's already in the output.
No need for the HEAD tag, it's already in the output.
For JavaScript use the panel below or the Resources panel for external files.
For external CSS files use the Resources panel on the left.
```

All I want to do is to show the following in jsfiddle:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css"/>

<!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick-theme.css"/>


 </head>
  <body>
<div>new1</div>
  <div class="your-class">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/benjones337/vnxxdcb7/6/

Comment: You'd better not to ask questions like this at stackoverflow.

Comment: Where do I ask them  then?

Comment: @mygoare: Questions about coding HTML/CSS/JS in JSFiddle are perfectly on-topic here. It's support questions like "I lost my password!!!" that don't belong here.

Comment: @BoltClock But the question is not about coding, it is about how to use jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

jsfiddle automatically adds the head and body tag for you. You need to remove those from your HTML. And for each CSS/JS file you need to add it via the External resource section. Basically copy the CSS and JS url one by one and click on the "+" button. Also, please use a service like cdnjs with https to load your files otherwise you will get mixed content error.

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>XML Parsing demo</h1>
        </div>        
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="cars-data">

            </ul>
        </div>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="cars">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-theme="a" href="#index">Back</a>          
            <h1></h1>
        </div>        
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="car-data">

            </ul>
            <img src=""width="100%" style="height: auto;" id="car-img"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

See my sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7vasdu3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [jsFiddle Documents](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#html) it says,

For HTML

- > Code entered in this panel will be rendered inside body of the
  >   document, that is between  and .
  >
  > Warning Please do not enter doctype, body etc. into the HTML panel.
  >   These tags are placed automatically.

For CSS

- > Code entered in this panel will be placed in the header’s style block,
  >   that is betweeen `<style>` and `</style>`.
  >
  > Note If there is a need to edit the header one can use a CSS panel
  >   hack

For JavaScript

- > Code entered in this panel will be placed in header’s script block,
  >   that is between `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>`

If there is a need to edit the header with Bootrap CDN's kind of links, one can add it in the side bar in the *External Resources* Tab as follows(add only the links),

[image]

If you want to change the Javascript versions,JQuery you can add as it as follows, by clicking that JavaScript button.

[image]

Here's JSFiddle example:https://jsfiddle.net/a37Ls5e9/2/

If you feeling uncomfortable with JsFiddle, use [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/pen/) instead.In [codepen](http://codepen.io/) you don't need to worry about pasting your head and body tags.Just paste it as usual.